# Local jnlp application blocked by java security

Tags: java, security, jnlp

I have an HP Proliant remote application card installed in my server, and it uses a java app (jnlp) for KVM access. Due to the incorrect way it's configured, no browser will run the jnlp file it provides; they all just download the file, and then I've just manually run it from my file manager.

Enter Java 8, where medium security is no longer an option. When I try to run the jnlp file, it tells me it's blocked by java security, so how can I run this jnlp file now? I've tried adding localhost and 127.0.0.1 to the exceptions list, but that didn't help.